# Where can I get the OpenGL graphics header files?

Tags: c, linux, opengl, ubuntu, header-files

I want to compile an OpenGL program but I don't have the necessary headers. Maybe you know how to get these?

```
#include <GL/glx.h>    /* this includes the necessary X headers */
#include <GL/gl.h>

#include <X11/X.h>    /* X11 constant (e.g. TrueColor) */
#include <X11/keysym.h>
```

It's the OpenGL example from the Codeblocks IDE that I'm trying to get running under ubuntu .

Comment: You can search package contents; e.g. http://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=GL%2Fglx.h&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any or install `apt-file` locally.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. My OpenGL program compiles and runs on MS WIndows with Visual Studio and now I want to make it run on ubuntu and see which changes I need to make. On MS WIndows I could just add windows.h and gl.h and the program compiled and runs. With Linux it seems I havae to search for and/or download library header files to compile and make opengl work.

Comment: Yeah, `apt-get install mesa-common-dev` and probably something like `x11proto-core-dev` for the general X11 files. That these are not installed by default is a feature, not a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OpenGL headers are part of Mesa, and the X11 headers are in Xorg's protocol development package.

Answer (score 1):

I installed the following packages:

- freeglut and freeglut-dev
- libgl1-mesa-dev
- libglu1-mesa and libglu1-mesa-dev
- libgl1-mesa-glx
- libx11-dev
- mesa-common-dev

and all their dependencies, after which I can directly include the headers you mentioned in my C program.

If you want to know the paths of these headers, do `locate gl.h`, `locate glx.h`, `locate X.h` and `locate keysym.h`. Be sure to `sudo updatedb` before you use `locate`.

Comment: You can also `grep /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list` or just the `list` files of selected packages. I'm sure there's a way with `grep-dctrl` or a related tool, too.